# Bitcoinj Spend from a address directly without wallet

Tags: bitcoinj, java

I am stuck trying to send coins from arbitary privateKey in bitcoinj. How can I make the following function work without using the Kit or Wallet classes?

```
@Override
public String transferCoin( ECKey sendingAdress, String destinationAddress, BigDecimal coins) throws Exception {
    return null;
}
```

Additionally I need to receive the notifications of coins being received on any address in the database, how can I achieve it without the wallet Class?